# Google Chrome app: Any SSH/SFTP JS libraries?

Tags: javascript, ssh, google-chrome-extension

I've been going through the samples for Google Chrome extension/app development and liked some of them. Especially the Telnet client example here:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/telnet

Is there a library/source that I can use with google Chrome for an SSH client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two years ago, I tried to find SSH/SFTP JavaScript Library, however, I could not find any libraries. Therefore, I created my app with libssh2. That is, I created [NaCl module](https://github.com/yoichiro/chrome_mysql_admin/tree/master/app/nacl_src) with C++ to use the libssh2 C library. Also, I created the [SFTP client NaCl module](https://github.com/yoichiro/chromeos-filesystem-sftp/tree/master/app/nacl_src) with libssh2 library as well.

And, you can also refer the source code of [SSH Client app](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform/assets/+/HEAD/chromeapps/ssh_client).

Probably, it is difficult to calculate encryption/decryption for SSH2 negotiation protocol with JavaScript...